# Integrate Building Wayfinder in .net desktop application

Tags: .net, wpf, desktop-application

I want to integrate a map of a Mall/Building having 7 floors in a desktop application.

After integration I have to highlight searched path (one shop to another shop) also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is "How to do it?, then:

Create a logic that will map the image maps to an actual squares array that represent areas on the map.

This will allow you to calculate path from one shop to another, in case both are on the same floor. In case shops are on a different floors, you map the path from the current location to a stairway or elevator and then, on a destination floor to a target shop.

The good algorithm for path finding is Dijkstra’s algorithm. You will find many implementations available, but it's always best to practice and implement one yourself.

Comment: can you explain process in details?

Comment: Viral, I doubt you are going to get an answer in more detail than that. You should just start creating an app and ask along the way in more detailed manner.

Comment: How can i determine the exact location of searched place on a map(Image).

Comment: Viral, I see what you are trying to ask, but the policy forbids long conversation in comments. Creating an app strategy is a one thing, that I have described, but map search is another. Consider marking this question as answered or wait for another answer, but in any way create another question for a different topic, even if it is within the scope of the same project you are working on.